# Create app-bound playlist on Spotify

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to create an app-bound playlist? 
It's possible to create a playlist for a user, but how will I know which one that is when they move away from my app?

Ideally, I would only need to be able to create/edit 1 playlist.

Edit: Have found this http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#appsthatcreateplaylisturi:s
But if anyone has great ideas, I'm still open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out yourself, you can't create a playlist in a user's library that's somehow linked to your application using the Spotify Apps API.

I thought it'd be a good idea to also quote the relevant part of the Integration Guidelines that you've [linked to](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#appsthatcreateplaylisturi%3as):

> If you want to generate and save the user’s personal playlists in the
>   app, you should **not** keep playlist information **only** saved within the
>   app. Playlist information should instead be handled by utilizing user
>   playlists, so that the user can access playlists as usual. They
>   shouldn’t have to go to the app to access a certain playlist that they
>   have created.

**Suggestion**:
I think there's several ways to do what you want to do though.

One way could be to let a user create a new playlist using your application and save it to the user's library, and at the same time save the playlist URI to your own back end. As you've noted, playlist URIs are obfuscated (e.g. they look like *spotify:user:@:playlist:783BHaT7Xb8K5VyYstxsj3* instead of *spotify:user:thelinmichael:playlist:783BHaT7Xb8K5VyYstxsj3*, the username is replaced by @ for the currently logged in user, and @xxx.. for other users). You could still save the last part of the URI, which I **believe** is unique for every playlist. Using a hashmap to map that part of the playlist URI to properties you want to keep track of would let you do quick lookups of a user's playlists to see if they are associated to your app. You could iterate though the user's library to gather all obfuscated URIs, and send them to your backend in a single HTTP request. The response from your server could be the index of the library playlists that matched the playlist on your backend, along with the properties you've mapped to it. Again, this was just a suggestion and possibly not the best way forward but I hope it gave you some ideas. :-)